# Calculation issue With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it is very simple.But Still it is not working.I am multiplying a input number with a fixed number,but is not showing the expected result.it always shows the Error message "Please enter some value" even i enter some integer e.g. 6.
This is Html Code.

```
 <input type="text" class="cc"  id="getdata" />
  <div id="result"> <input type="text" id="show" /></div>
   <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate" />
```

This is JQuery Code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#calculate").click(function () {
            if ($("#input").val() != ''  && $("#input").val() != undefined) {
             $("#result").html("total value is::" + parseInt($("#input").val()) * 5);
            }
            else {
                $("#result").html("Please enter some value");
            }
         });
         });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Can anyone tell me please how to concatenate all clicked values of different buttons in a textbox?I want to show previous and current clicked value of button in a textbox. 
Thank you.

Comment: Course :) On any question you ask you can tick on the greyed out arrow next to an answer. This marks it as accepted and any future visitors know that this was the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Do you not mean `#getdata`? Where is `#input`?

Replace `("#input")` with `("#getdata")` in your code.

**Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdKJN/).**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#calculate").click(function () {
     if ($("#getdata").val() != '' && $("#getdata").val() != undefined) {
         $("#result").html("total value is::" + parseInt($("#getdata").val()) * 5);
     } else {
         $("#result").html("Please enter some value");
     }
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no input whose id is "input". The [jquery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `#somestring` is looking for an element whose id is `somestring`.

Replace `("#input")` by `("#getdata")` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no field with the ID `input` in the HTML you posted, yet your jQuery is looking for one. Perhaps you meant `$('#show')`

With jQuery issues, ALWAYS suspect the selector before even wondering what else might be wrong. Confirm it actually finds the elements you think it does - never assume.

```
console.log($('#input').length); //0
```

Comment: Thank all.I just changed it and forget to rename.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#input").val() != ''  && $("#input").val() != undefined) {
```

You dont have any field anywhere in your markup with the id `input`!

I think you intended all the instances of `#input` in that script to be `#getdata`, but you should also only read its value once into a variable and use that:

```
$("#calculate").click(function () {
     var val = $('#getdata').val();
        if (val != ''  && val != undefined) {
         $("#result").html("total value is::" + parseInt(val) * 5);
        }
        else {
            $("#result").html("Please enter some value");
        }
     });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/82pf4/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#calculate").click(function () {
                if ($("#getdata").val() != ''  && $("#getdata").val() != undefined) {
                 $("#result").html("total value is::" + parseInt($("#getdata").val()) * 5);
                }
                else {
                    $("#result").html("Please enter some value");
                }
             });
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PcYPR/5/)

I think that is what you want.

```
<input type="text" class="cc"  id="getdata" />
<input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate" />
<div id="result"></div>​

<script>
$("#calculate").click(calculate);
$("#getdata").keypress(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13)
        calculate();
});

function calculate()
{
    var $getData = $("#getdata");
    var $result= $("#result");

    if ($getData .val() != ''  && $getData .val() != undefined && !isNaN($getData .val()))
    {
        $result.append((parseInt($getData .val()) * 5) + "<p>");
    }
    else
    {   
        $result.append("Please enter some value<p>");
    }
    $getData .val("").focus();
}
​
</script>
```